# How can i stop the sound on Expo-AV REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm using this function for the play sound files. I want the sound to stop when I click the button

```
function playSound(){
  
    Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      selectedAnimals.soundUrl,
      { shouldPlay: true }
    ).then((res)=>{
      res.sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((status)=>{
        if(!status.didJustFinish) return;
        
        res.sound.unloadAsync().catch(()=>{});
      });
    }).catch((error)=>{});
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

when creating the sound you simply need to assign it to a value

```
const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(asset);
```

and then you can use other methods of the sound object

```
await sound.sound.pauseAsync()
await sound.sound.stopAsync()
```

etc

hope it helps